# How to Retrieve Data to My RecyclerView from Database, My RecyclerView Show Empty

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

[My Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNYxh.png) and [How my RecyclerView display after my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhky8.png)

This is how I save my data

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mCurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Email").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child("Appointment").push();
            String name = nameTxt.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = addressTxt.getText().toString().trim();
            String tel = telTxt.getText().toString().trim();
            String date = dateApp.getText().toString().trim();
            String time = timeApp.getText().toString().trim();

            //Adding values
            db.child("Name").setValue(name);
            db.child("Address").setValue(address);
            db.child("Tel").setValue(tel);
            db.child("Date").setValue(date);
            db.child("Time").setValue(time);

            //Storing values to Firebase
            Toast.makeText(AddAppointment.this,"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(AddAppointment.this,Appointment.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
```

My code to retrieve data to RecyclerView "but no success"

```
public class ViewAppointment extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private DatabaseReference db;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<AppointmentData> mAdapter;

    ImageButton refreshBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_appointment);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Email").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child("Appointment");
        db.keepSynced(true);
        addListenerOnButton();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AppointmentData, myViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AppointmentData, myViewHolder>
            (AppointmentData.class,R.layout.model,myViewHolder.class,db) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, AppointmentData model, int position) {
                viewHolder.nameTxt.setText(model.getName());
                viewHolder.dateApp.setText(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.timeApp.setText(model.getTime());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView nameTxt,dateApp,timeApp;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            nameTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
            dateApp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAppointment);
            timeApp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeAppointment);
        }
    }
}
```

AppointmentData.java

```
public class AppointmentData {

    private String name, tel, address, time, date;

    public AppointmentData() {

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public AppointmentData(String name, String tel, String address, String time, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.address = address;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Model.xml RecyclerView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cast_intro_overlay_button_background_color">

        <TextView
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dateAppointment" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timeAppointment"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

ViewAppointment.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a static list of data to verify your RecyclerView works correctly before even touching the database?

Comment: no~ i just follow the tutorial and modified my code... but i dont know where error

Comment: Your image shows two cards are loaded, so the problem exists in your layouts or how the text is displayed

Comment: but from my layout "model.xml" there. should be correct and after that i retrieve by using this code

Comment: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AppointmentData, myViewHolder> adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AppointmentData, myViewHolder>(
            AppointmentData.class,R.layout.model,myViewHolder.class,db
    )

Comment: {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, AppointmentData model, int position) {
            viewHolder.nameTxt.setText(model.getName());
            viewHolder.dateApp.setText(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.timeApp.setText(model.getTime());


        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView nameTxt,dateApp,timeApp;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        nameTxt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        dateApp= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateAppointment);
        timeApp=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeAppointment);

    }
}

Comment: Stop using the comments. [edit] your question to include additional code

Comment: I'm saying your code gets two elements from the database fine. Please take the time to debug and set breakpoints in the data returned from the database or make a static arraylist of objects in an Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in `AppointmentData` class. You have named all your member variables in lowercase which does not exactly match the key name in your database (because the first letter of every key name is in uppercase). So make sure that the key name and the member variables of your `AppointmentData` class are matching.

Answer (score 0):

I do a little observation about your problem and it seems like just a small mistake. I am referring to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34883389/4088357

> We'll create a Java class that represents a Blog Post. Like last time, we have to make sure that our field names match the names of the properties in the Firebase database and give the class a default, parameterless constructor.

So, you can change your code when you saved the values in Firebase database:

```
//Adding values
db.child("name").setValue(name);
db.child("address").setValue(address);
db.child("tel").setValue(tel);
db.child("date").setValue(date);
db.child("time").setValue(time);
```

Comment: i have a question. if i want to delete one of the RecyclerView and data from firebase, how to i write the code?

Comment: You're welcome @YewGuanKoh. Please create new question for that problem.