# Inserting data into firebase not fully inserted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a project that helps logs users profile. I am using Firebase Real-time database as the database of my mobile app. Now, the thing is, I want the user to be able to update their data (medical data), and make it into a graph. So I had an idea to add the updated data as a child data from the first input-ed data. The child data insert works fine, but in my database it only shows half of the data input-ed. I need help so the data is input-ed fully.

My UpdateProfileActivity code:

```
public class UpdateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail, userAge, userHeight, userWeight, userListening, userSights, userHeadsize, userBirthday;
    private Button regButton;
    private TextView userLogin;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ImageView userProfilePic;
    String email, name, age, password, height, weight, headsize, listening, sights, birthday, birthdaydate, birthdaymonth, birthdayyear;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateProfileActivity";

    String bddate, bdmonth, bdyear;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_profile);
        setupUIViews();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                    //sendEmailVerification();
                    sendUserData();

                    Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "Data Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                    //finish();
                    /*startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));*/


                }


        });

    }


    private void setupUIViews() {
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);

        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
        regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        userLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserLogin);
        userAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        userHeadsize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeadSize);
        userHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        userWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        userSights = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSights);
        userListening = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etListening);
        userProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
        userBirthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Birthday);


        userBirthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        UpdateProfileActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                bddate = String.valueOf(day);
                bdmonth = String.valueOf(month);
                bdyear = String.valueOf(year);


                userBirthday.setText(bddate + "/" + bdmonth+ "/" +bdyear);
            }
        };




    }

    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;

        name = userName.getText().toString();
        email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        age = userAge.getText().toString();
        height = userHeight.getText().toString();
        weight = userWeight.getText().toString();
        listening = userListening.getText().toString();
        sights = userSights.getText().toString();
        headsize = userHeadsize.getText().toString();
        birthday = userBirthday.getText().toString();


        if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || height.isEmpty() || weight.isEmpty() || listening.isEmpty() || sights.isEmpty() || headsize.isEmpty() || birthday.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }




        return result;
    }


    private void sendUserData() {

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        DatabaseReference childRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(myRef.getKey());


        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(age, email, name, height, weight, headsize, listening, sights, bddate, bdmonth, bdyear);
        childRef.push().setValue(userProfile);
    }


}
```

My UserProfile class code:

```
public class UserProfile {
    public String userAge;
    public String userEmail;
    public String userName;
    public String userHeight, userWeight, userListening, userSights, userHeadsize, userBirthday, bdmonth, bdyear;


    public UserProfile(){

    }

    public UserProfile(String userAge, String userEmail, String userName, String userheight, String userweight, String headsize, String listening, String sights, String birthday, String bdmonth, String bdyear) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userHeight = userheight;
        this.userWeight = userweight;
        this.userListening = listening;
        this.userSights = sights;
        this.userHeadsize = headsize;
        this.userBirthday = birthday;
        this.bdmonth = bdmonth;
        this.bdyear = bdyear;
    }

    public String getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return userHeight;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return userWeight;
    }

    public String getHeadSize() {
        return userHeadsize;
    }

    public String getListening() {
        return userListening;
    }

    public String getSights() {
        return userSights;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return userBirthday;
    }

    public String getBirthdayMonth() {
        return bdmonth;
    }

    public String getBirthdayYear() {
        return bdyear;
    }
}
```

The correct data input should actually be like this:
[image: here]

But instead it showed like this:
[image]

Comment: Do the fields that are been left out contain null values?

Comment: Make the fields private, and possibly try adding a `toString` override [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882779/firebase-to-custom-java-object).

Comment: No it doesn't @MadhanVaradhodiyil

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your solution! @JamesPoag

Comment: @JamesPoag thanks! The solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the data inside an Map object and the push the map object to child.

like below

Please check the code inside sendUserData(), I have added new lines of code.

Hope this helps.

```
   public class UpdateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText userName, userPassword, userEmail, userAge, userHeight, userWeight, userListening, userSights, userHeadsize, userBirthday;
    private Button regButton;
    private TextView userLogin;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ImageView userProfilePic;
    String email, name, age, password, height, weight, headsize, listening, sights, birthday, birthdaydate, birthdaymonth, birthdayyear;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateProfileActivity";

    String bddate, bdmonth, bdyear;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_profile);
        setupUIViews();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                    //sendEmailVerification();
                    sendUserData();

                    Toast.makeText(UpdateProfileActivity.this, "Data Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                    //finish();
                    /*startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));*/


                }


        });

    }


    private void setupUIViews() {
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);

        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
        regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        userLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserLogin);
        userAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        userHeadsize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeadSize);
        userHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        userWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
        userSights = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSights);
        userListening = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etListening);
        userProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
        userBirthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Birthday);


        userBirthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        UpdateProfileActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                bddate = String.valueOf(day);
                bdmonth = String.valueOf(month);
                bdyear = String.valueOf(year);


                userBirthday.setText(bddate + "/" + bdmonth+ "/" +bdyear);
            }
        };




    }

    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;

        name = userName.getText().toString();
        email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        age = userAge.getText().toString();
        height = userHeight.getText().toString();
        weight = userWeight.getText().toString();
        listening = userListening.getText().toString();
        sights = userSights.getText().toString();
        headsize = userHeadsize.getText().toString();
        birthday = userBirthday.getText().toString();


        if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || height.isEmpty() || weight.isEmpty() || listening.isEmpty() || sights.isEmpty() || headsize.isEmpty() || birthday.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }




        return result;
    }


    private void sendUserData() {

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        DatabaseReference childRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(myRef.getKey());

        Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();
        users.put(firebaseAuth.getUid(), new UserProfile(age, email, name, height, weight, headsize, listening, sights, bddate, bdmonth, bdyear));


        // UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(age, email, name, height, weight, headsize, listening, sights, bddate, bdmonth, bdyear);
        childRef.push().setValue(users);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **DatabaseReference.CompletionListener**

```
childRef.push().setValue(userProfile,new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference reference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write message", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                }
            });
```